# WPF Populating Datagrid's DataGridCheckBoxColumn with data / setting ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have simple WPF app with datagrid, where the user set date from and date to (date range) and then i programatically add DataGridCheckColumns. Till here everything works just fine. Then, when I want to populate datagrid's DataGridCheckColumns I simply find no data - I have propably set wrong the binding or something.

Here is my code:

```
ObservableCollection<List<bool>> days = new ObservableCollection<List<bool>>();
DataTable daysList = new DataTable();
List<bool> listbools = new List<bool>();
List<List<bool>> ll = new List<List<bool>>();
int c = 0;
for (DateTime d = (DateTime)DatumOd.SelectedDate; d <= (DateTime)DatumDo.SelectedDate; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    //DataGridRooms.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = d.ToString().Substring(0,6) });
    daysList.Columns.Add(d.ToString().Substring(0, 6));
    listbools.Add(c%2 ==1?true:false);
    DataGridCheckBoxColumn dd = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn() 
    { 
        Header = d.ToString().Substring(0, 6),
        Binding = new Binding("Binding listbools, mode=TwoWay"),
        IsReadOnly = false,
        DisplayIndex = c
    };
    
    DataGridRooms.Columns.Add(dd);
    c++;
}

daysList.Rows.Add(listbools);

ll.Add(listbools);
days.Add(listbools);
//days.Add(daysList);
DataGridRooms.ItemsSource = ll;
```

Here is what I tried already (DataTable, List, ObservableCollection of List,..).
Here is how it looks now.
[image: Right now datagrid looks like this]

And here is what I want.

[image: Here is how it should look like]

What else, the datagrid shows extra column Capacity and Count, I guess its because of wrong DataGridCheckBoxColumn's binding or DataGrid's ItemsSource, but I can't figure it out.
Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be simple to use DataTable (it has tabular structure - columns and rows - just like DataGrid):

```
DataTable daysList = new DataTable();

// creating columns
for (DateTime d = new DateTime(2020, 12, 1); d <= new DateTime(2020, 12, 14); d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    string columnName = d.ToString("dd.MM");
    daysList.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(bool));

    DataGridCheckBoxColumn dd = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn() 
    {
        Header = columnName,
        // have to use [ and ] because columnName contains a dot. It is DataTable quirk
        Binding = new Binding("[" + columnName + "]"),
    };
    
    DataGridRooms.Columns.Add(dd);
}

// creating rows with data
for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
{
    var row = daysList.NewRow();
    
    // filling cells in a row
    for(int c = 0; c < daysList.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
        row[c] = (c % ( r + 2)) == 0; // just an example
    }

    daysList.Rows.Add(row);
}
DataGridRooms.ItemsSource = daysList.DefaultView;
```

[image: DataGrid]

Comment: Ahh, now its populatin dat, but datagrid shows repeated columns but not populated even if I just copy + past your code. Does it mean I have something else wrong? And to be honest, you just saved my sleep. Thank very much! BTW I will accept and upvote your answer after figuring out next bug.

Comment: try `DataGridRooms.AutoGenerateColumns=false;` before setting ItemsSource